# Using DTO in asp.net website for 4-level architecture

Tags: asp.net, dto

I have few concerns about DTO. I am trying to create 4 level architecture for my asp.net website. I will have DTO, BLL, DAL and Presentation Layer.

1. Do I need to create DTO for each table? I have almost 100 tables and some of the tables have 70-100 columns.
2. For complicated query where I join 5-8 tables, How do I approach this? DO I need to get DTO for each table and then run Linq Query on all those DTO List in BLL then return result back to aspx page?

If there are other suggestions, please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You will only  need a DTO when you need to pass a simple object, perhaps from the DAL repository (where your DTO = a table, stored procedure result or view result) to a domain / BLL object which might well be an aggregate object providing a logical view of the domain rather than a one to one mapping from the database. It all depends on how you are 'growing' your application.

If you are going to have loads of similar DTO's it can be a good idea to use a tool, like [AutoMapper](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/) - it will save you a lot of time writing boring mapping code.

Answer (score 0):

Some people insist on having separate DTOs for every single service call you make. Depending on the complexity of the logic, this could potentially lead to much more than 100 different DTOs.

I prefer a generic approach, where you build a DTO model with a 1-1 correspondence between DTOs and domain entities. In this approach, you'll have 100 DTO tables. If you use any tool to automatically create code (Codesmith, T4), creating the DTO layer can be easy.

The other concern, returning compound results can be tackled with a generic DTO container to hold your DTO classes:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/12/generic-dto-model-and-other-silverlight.html

(the section starts at the "Generic DTO Models)